# Build active architectures only no causing compile error

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, xcode7

I'm using Cocoapods as my dependency manager, however, my current project requires me to have a library that requires me to turn off "Build Active Architecture Only".
But upon turning it off, all my dependencies get screwed up, I get compile errors like:

> Module 'Alamofire' has no member 'request'

etc and this is happening to every single of my pods. Are there any workarounds for this? I'm using Xcode 7.

Answer (score 0):

This is very normal issue. If you are using pods then you need to select `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO`

> Steps to resolve the issue:

```
1. Go to Pods
2. Select 'Alamofire target' or select 'All Pods' (skip Tests)
3. Go to Build Settings > Build Active Architecture Only > No
```

That's it!

Comment: I'm sorry in my case is I only got the errors only when I set "Build Active Architectures" only to YES